# JDBC prepared statement to query JSON using json_exists

Tags: java, json, oracle, jdbc

I'm facing trouble transforming the below query to jdbc prepared statement and setting the parameters.

oracle query:

```
select * from TRANSACTION_DUMMY where ID = 'aa'
and JSON_EXISTS(TRANSACTION_DUMMY_INDEX FORMAT JSON, 
 '$.header.lineItems[*].status?(@=="complete")')
```

translated query:

```
select * from TRANSACTION_DUMMY where ID = ?
and JSON_EXISTS(TRANSACTION_DUMMY_INDEX FORMAT JSON, 
'$.header.lineItems[*].status?(@==?)')
```

the issue is how to set parameters in the query.
tried playing around with indexes but always getting the error, invalid column index.

any pointers how to handle the above scenario using java jdbc prepared statement?

thanks

Comment: what is the code you tried?

Comment: At first glance you probably need to escape the `?` in `status?`. That's part of your original query but jdbc will see it as a parameter so you have three parameters when you only want two

Comment: @Adam - that question mark, and the one after the equals sign - which is presumably the one the OP is trying to bind and which is thus throwing the error - should be ignored because they are inside a single-quoted string, which is treated as a text literal and not interpreted.

Comment: @AlexPoole: Ah!  So, the two question marks need to be treated differently, but I got the wrong one to change :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions010.htm#BABHAGEG), the second argument to `JSON_EXISTS` is a special string literal called `JSON_path_expression`.

If the value of the expression should change dynamically, it will be easiest to create it on the client (Java) side and then concatenate it into the query. You cannot pass the path expression as a bind variable because Oracle expects it to be a literal, i.e. a "parse-time constant". As you noticed, you'll get an `ORA-40454: path expression not a literal` error message if you try to pass the expression as a bind value.

The following code uses Java's `String.format()` for injecting the expression into the SQL template:

```
String sql = "select * from TRANSACTION_DUMMY where ID = 'aa' "
            + "and JSON_EXISTS(TRANSACTION_DUMMY_INDEX_FORMAT_JSON, %s)";
// here you could have some code for modifying jsonPathExpression dynamically, 
// e.g. changing the status based on some criteria
String jsonPathExpression = "'$.header.lineItems[*].status?(@==\"complete\")'";

try (Statement st = myConnection.createStatement(String.format(sql, jsonPathExpression))) {

    ResultSet st = ps.executeQuery();
    // Process result set
}
```

Comment: tried the above approach, it still results in java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index

Comment: Can you share more details about your problem -- _how_ did you try this? Is it possible that the error is caused by the `ResultSet` handling in your code (which is omitted in my example)?

Comment: actually the original problem of 'java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index' is resolved. running the above sample results in 'ORA-40454: path expression not a literal'. apologies for the confusion caused.

Comment: Modified the solution now; apparently you cannot use bind variables with the `JSON_EXISTS` function. You need to basically concatenate it into the query, but you can of course create the expression value somehow dynamically in Java.

Comment: the status to be checked against would be an input to the function. to concatenate it in the pathExpression and use to in createStatement wouldn't be right. we might be opening ourselves to sqlinjection. the other way around, a view can be constructed on the json index and query that view.

Comment: You probably have an enumerable set of allowed statuses. If this is the case, you can sanitize the input using e.g. an enum. Looks like there is no way to pass binds into `JSON_EXISTS`.

Comment: yup i agree, looks there is no way around.