# How to escape the ? character in a JDBC PreparedStatement when using Oracle 19c JSON_EXISTS filter

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am using Oracle 19c and I am trying to use the following SQL string with a `PreparedStatement`

```
SELECT * 
FROM   TEST_JSON2
WHERE  JSON_EXISTS(json_data, '$?(@[*] == ?)');
```

But I get the following exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
```

How can I escape the first question mark?
I found some a similar discussion but it refers to [MATCH_RECOGNIZE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42108242/whats-the-correct-way-to-escape-the-character-in-a-jdbc-preparedstatement-whe).
Also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26516204/how-do-i-escape-a-literal-question-mark-in-a-jdbc-prepared-statement) but still the correct answer is not clear to me.

Comment: Did you click through from the `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` answer to the documentation they linked and try the escape sequence `{\?\}` used in the example in that documentation?

Comment: Yes, I tried this with no luck - I guess it is specific to `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`...

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using? What JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: Oracle 19c - ojdbc8 (19.3.0.0)

Comment: You forgot to close the string literal, which might be confusing JDBC. Does it work if you do `JSON_EXISTS(json_data, '$?(@[*] == ?')` and the `?` is inside the string literal?

Comment: Typo error while writing the question - Sorry about that! In my code, it is correctly closed. But still throws the exception.

Answer (score 1):

It should be sufficient to just correct the typo where you forgot to terminate the string literal inside the `JSON_EXISTS` function call and then the `?` will be inside a string and JDBC will not parse it as a bind parameter.

---

If for some reason correcting the typo is insufficient then:

From the [OJDBC documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdbc/JDBC-reference-information.html#GUID-3454411C-5F24-4D46-83A9-5DA0BA704F5D) (which is subtly different from the documentation linked from the question):

> #### A.4.4 `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` Clause
>
> The `?` character is used as a token in `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` clause in Oracle Database 11g and later versions. As the JDBC standard defines the `?` character as a parameter marker, the JDBC Driver and the Server SQL Engine cannot distinguish between different uses of the same token.
>
> In earlier versions of JDBC Driver, if you want to interpret the `?` character as a `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` token and not as a parameter marker, then you must use a `Statement` instead of a `PreparedStatement` and disable escape processing. However, starting from Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.2), you can use the `'{\\ ... \\}'` syntax while using the `?` character, so that the JDBC driver does not process it as a parameter marker and allows the SQL engine to process it.

Following that, I think your code (correcting for the typo where you do not close the string literal and are missing a closing bracket in the JSON path expression) should be:

```java
String sql =
      "SELECT * "
    + "FROM   TEST_JSON2 "
    + "WHERE  JSON_EXISTS(json_data, {\\'$?(@[*] == ?)'\\})";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatatement(sql);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

or, to not use a `PreparedStatement` and just use a `Statement`:

```java
String sql =
      "SELECT * "
    + "FROM   TEST_JSON2 "
    + "WHERE  JSON_EXISTS(json_data, '$?(@[*] == ?)')";
Statement s = conn.createStatatement(sql);
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery();
```

Comment: I tried your first suggestion but it still produces an exception. Although I do not understand why you put the escape syntax around the whole expression and not escaping only the first question mark. Your 2n proposal, it is an option but I would like first to be completely sure that I cannot use prepared statement.

Comment: @georgeliatsos If you want to surround every `?`, you can try `JSON_EXISTS(json_data, '${\\?\\}(@[*] == {\\?\\}')` but the JDBC escape sequence is not limited to processing a single character so you can do the entire string literal in a single escape sequence.

Comment: OK, I guess the confusion originates from my misunderstanding, I was guessing that the second question mark should be as a placeholder for the parameter value while the first one is an explicit question mark used from the json_exists funtion.

Comment: @georgeliatsos That would be something like (untested): `JSON_EXISTS(json_data, '$?(@[*] == "' ||?||'")')` and then the first `?` would be inside the string literal and the second would be a bind variable.

Comment: As far as I understand based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48913687/jdbc-prepared-statement-to-query-json-using-json-exists/48914253#48914253 , it is not possible to use json_exists in a PreparedStatement and passing parameters in the special string literal.

Comment: @georgeliatsos That is correct, `JSON_EXISTS` expects a single literal value at the time the SQL engine compiles the statement (so the code in my previous comment will not work); what you can do is use string concatenation (with appropriate sanitation and escaping of your data) to build the JSON path expression in your Java code and include it into the SQL statement.